# Flood main thread with consuming tasks

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I would like to flood the main thread with random tasks for a certain amount of time in order to figure out how another part of my application would in this circumstances. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could just create an while-loop that never ends. Something like:

```
BOOL contunue = YES;
    while (contunue) {
        // Code
    }
```

That would run until you stop the program yourself.

**Edit:**

To add a timer to the above code, you could use `NSTimer` to change the value of `continue` to `NO` after a determined amount of time